# I am missing code coverage when I run npm test --code-coverage

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I am using an Angular 6 application. When I run the command `ng test --code-coverage` I get info if my tests are successful or failed but I don't get printed that in percentage like I should - so for example functions coverage is 80% etc.

After I run this command I can find the coverage folder in my application and I know if I open `index.html` I will get the percentages there, but I need to have this feature "live" so when i make changes the `ng test` command will re-run. I can't open `index.html` on every change I make.

My `angular.json` file - test property:

```json
 "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
```

I tried explicitly adding `"codeCoverage": true` in my `angular.json` configuration but it still does not print the percentages in my terminal.

Comment: You need to configure the _reporters_ for that feature. See https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-coverage/blob/master/docs/configuration.md, as the Angular docs suggest; the default is that only the HTML reporter is enabled.

Comment: This seems to be out of date.I don't get such a files in my angular 6 application. Btw when i used angular 10 i got by default the code coverage :S